# Create a vector with values from a Numpy array selected according to criteria in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I am working with a pandas df that contains two columns with integers. For each data of the df, I would like to select these two integers, use them as [row,column] pairs to extract values from a np.array and create a new np.array with the extracted values.

In more detail, my df contains the following entries:

```
             State  FutureState
DATE                                                         
1947-10-01       0            0
1948-01-01       0            1
1948-04-01       1            1
1948-07-01       1            1
```

For each `Date`, I would like to select the [State,FutureState] pair and extract the corresponding [row,column] item from the following np.array, called `P`:

```
array([[ 0.7,  0.3],
       [ 0.4,  0.6]])
```

With these values, I would like to create a new np.array called `Transition`, which contains of the following values:

```
[P[0,0],P[0,1],P[1,1],P[1,1]] = [0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6]
```

The pairs `[0,0], [0,1], [1,1] [1,1]` used as index for the array `P` are the values for `[State,FutureState]` for each date (  1947-10-01, 1948-01-01 , 1948-04-01, 1948-07-01 ).

I already tried to solve my problem in a lot of different ways but to no avail. Can somebody kindly suggest how to successfully create the `Transition` vector?

Comment: Sorry it is a little unclear what you are asking, can you provide more info, for instance where do you get the p[0,1] value from as it's unclear which date this is an example for

Comment: @EdChum: Thank you for your comment and please excuse the confusion. I added a line below the `[P[0,0],P[0,1],P[1,1],P[1,1]] = [0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6]` line. Is this enough to make my question clearer?

Comment: This works but I'm not that familiar with numpy shaping: `P[df.values.reshape([4,2])[1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
p[df.State, df.FutureState]
```

Here is the full code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

txt = """             State  FutureState                                                        
1947-10-01       0            0
1948-01-01       0            1
1948-04-01       1            1
1948-07-01       1            1"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)
p = np.array([[ 0.7,  0.3], [ 0.4,  0.6]])
p[df.State, df.FutureState]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df.apply(lambda x:P[x[0],x[1]], axis=1)
```

It does what you describe, go row-wise (so apply over `axis=1`)  along `df` and use the entries as index for selecting in `P`.